# What are alternatives about FingerprintManager in Lollipop version

Tags: android

Minimum Sdk Version in my app is 21 and [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager#isHardwareDetected()) is supported in Marshmallow version and above so what can I use with Lollipop version?

Comment: What would you do with it on API 21? AFAIK there are no devices with fingerprint sensor with API 21.

Comment: Oppo F1S has...

Comment: @laalto There is no Fingerprint feature in Lollipop?

Comment: @laalto I realized that now, Thank you

Comment: Anyway there's `FingerprintManagerCompat` that backports the functionality to lower API levels too.